# Change Source URL in iFrame Based on current time

Tags: javascript, wordpress, iframe, vimeo

We have three weekly livestream events that use unique iframe embed codes, but need all three to share an iframe video embed container on our wordpress site and only show the active stream. Our events are Sundays at 8:30am, 10am and 11:30am. How do I change the source url in the iframe based on the current time of day?

For instance, if I visit the site at 9am on Sunday, the 8:30am event would be playing or the event displaying in the iframe. Whereas if I visited the site at 10:15am the 10am event would be playing or displaying in the iframe.

The goal is to have one video embed container on our homepage so that whenever anyone visits the site during those times a live event is displayed.

Comment: You can create a custom shortcode that checks for the date-time (when page is accessed) and change the iframe URL based on the date-time criteria. Then you can add the shortcode to any wordpress page or post.

Comment: That's awesome @ozgur! Thank you. I do not have much coding experience to be honest, how would I best go about this?

Comment: I posted my sample code as an answer. Hope it helps...

Comment: So grateful @ozgur. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Your welcome @CP50 . Please consider accepting the answer if it works for you

Answer (score 0):

This code defines 3 different event times and checks if `today` is `Sunday.
Tested and works.

You can include it in your child theme's functions php or install [Code Snippets](https://wordpress.org/plugins/code-snippets/) plugin and add it as a new snippet.

Make sure you set your correct `time zone`. For test purposes I've used Europe/Istanbul as my timezone. Here is the list of [time zones](https://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php) you can use.

Another important note is: Due to security, most websites do not allow them to be accessed inside an `iframe`. You may get `'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'` error if the URL in iframe has this restriction.

I commented all sections in the code, so you can easily change your event times and event day in case needed. I assumed end time would be around 14:00. You can change it in the code.

After setting up, just add `[iframe_content]` **shortcode** to the page that you want to display your iframe.

```
function shortcode_iframe() {
    // Set the correct timezone
    date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Istanbul");
    
    // Set event start times
    $start1 = date("08:30");
    $start2 = date("10:00");
    $start3 = date("11:30");
    $end = date ("14:00"); // No events after this time
    
    // Current time and day
    $now = date("H:i");
    $day = date('D');

    // Define URLs for each condition
    $url1 = 'https://www.domain1.com';
    $url2 = 'https://www.domain2.com';
    $url3 = 'https://www.domain3.com';

    // Check for no event condition
    $noevent = true;
    
    // Check conditions only if today is Sunday
    if ($day == "Sun") {

        // Event 1
        if ($now >= $start1 && $now < $start2) {
            $url = $url1;
            $noevent = false;
        }

        // Event 2
        if ($now >= $start2 && $now < $start3) {
            $url = $url2;
            $noevent = false;
        }
        
        // Event 3
        if ($now >= $start3 && $now < $end) {
            $url = $url3;
            $noevent = false;
        }
        
    }

    // Generate iframe code if between registered event times
    if ($noevent) {
        $iframeelement="No event is registered at this time";
    }
    else {
        $iframeelement = '<iframe src="'.$url.'" style="height:600px; width:800px;"></iframe>';                     
    }
    return $iframeelement;      

    
}
add_shortcode('iframe_content', 'shortcode_iframe');
```